# Show open set $U ⊆ \overline{U ∩ A}$ where $A$ is dense in topological space $X$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space. Let $U$ be an open set in
$X$ and $A$ be a set in $X$ so that $\overline A = X$.

I want to show that $U ⊆ \overline{U ∩ A}$ (where the overline indicates closure).

Hmm so let $x\in U$. I could not prove $x\in \overline{U ∩ A}$ directly, so tried supposing for a contradiction that $x\notin \overline{U ∩ A}$. Then $x\in X\setminus \overline{U ∩ A}$ which is open. But I am not sure if this is the right rack~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x \in U$. To show that $x \in \overline{U \cap A}$, we need to show that every open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ intersects $U \cap A$: this is easy as $U \cap V$ is also an open neighbourhood of $x$ and so intersects $A$ (as $\overline{A}=X$) and so $$\emptyset \neq(U \cap V) \cap A = V \cap (U \cap A)$$

QED.

As a consequence $\overline{U} = \overline{A \cap U}$ (the left to right inclusion we now finish by taking the closure on both sides of the above; the right to left inclusion is obvious from $U \cap A \subseteq U$).

Comment: May I ask tho, how taking closure on both sides of the equation gives the left to right inclusion?

Comment: @Homaniac general fact: $C \subseteq D$ implies $\overline{C} \subseteq \overline{D}$ (i.e. taking closures on both sides). So $U \subseteq \overline{U \cap A}$ implies $\overline{U} \subseteq \overline{\overline{U \cap A}} = \overline{U \cap A}$ (as double closure equals single closure).

Comment: ah okay, but $U ⊆ \overline{U ∩ A}$ was precisely what I wanted to prove so why am I using it to prove $\overline{U} ⊆ \overline{U ∩ A}$?  Sorry, I must be missing something simple here ><

Comment: Oh did you mean the proof was already completed after the QED in your answer? The "As a consequence.." portion was just an additional remark?

Comment: @Homaniac Precisely, your result is done after QED (that's what it means). I just wanted to point out the corollary which often follows and is its raison d'être.

Answer (score 0):

Following your approach  note that $U\cap (X\setminus \overline  {(U\cap A)})$ is an open set containing $x$. Hence it must intersect the  dense set $A$. But its intersection with $A$ is empty because $X\setminus \overline  {(U\cap A)}$ is contained in $X\setminus  {U\cap A}$

Comment: Ah thanks, may I clarify in the last sentence, why does the containment imply the intersection is empty?

Comment: If a set $B$ is contained in the complement of $U \cap A$ and also in $A$ then it cannot intersect $A$.